# Why do i get ValueError inputing an int literal

Tags: python, valueerror

Here we have 3 inputs in a row

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
b *= 60
c += b
print((a+c)//60)
print((a+c)%60)
```

Why do I get ValueError in the second one?

```
480
1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Пит\Projects\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: your code works perfectly. I think you're inputting a space for some reason

Comment: Look carefully at the error you received. The `''` at the end tells you that it received an empty string rather than something that can be converted to a string.

Comment: You might want to add an output to `input` to see where you enter what. Example: `a = int(input('A: '))`

Comment: You almost certainly accidentally added an extra blank line between `480` and `1` you're not showing us. If you actually entered `480`, then `1`, then nothing else, the error would be on the `c` line, not the `b`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBViEzr0QjM6@gtERDU5MrCV0gGVOFlq2CmQFQQttWIYmroAgkq5Gonaypr29moIksoArk//9vYmHAZcjFBQA "Python 3 – Try It Online") It works fine if you enter three numbers back to back: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBViEzr0QjM6@gtERDU5MrCV0gGVOFlq2CmQFQQttWIYmroAgkq5Gonaypr29moIksoArk//9vYmHAZchlDAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: For debugging, you might separate input from parsing, making it `a, b, c = input(), input(), input()` then do `print(f'{a!r}, {b!r}, {c!r}')` to see what you're reading from those three `input` calls before converting them to `int`; clearly it's not what you think (given you're getting empty input(s)).

Answer (score 0):

You have entered a non-numeric value, so type casting failed with the reported error message. I would make a separate function to input an integer value, for example:

```
def input_int(input_prompt: str):
    string_value = ''
    while not string_value.isnumeric():
        string_value = input(input_prompt)
        if string_value.isnumeric():
            return int(string_value)
        else:
            print('You entered non-numeric value. Please input numeric value.')


a = input_int('Enter a: ')
b = input_int('Enter b: ')
c = a + b
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inadvertently pressed `enter` or your keyboard did it for you, without you realising, the result will be:

```
>>> b = int(input())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Seems a plausible cause.